# Correctly simulating a Poisson process at population level

Tags: random-variables, poisson-distribution, uniform-distribution

I have a string sequence that undergoes random mutation per position with $P_{mutate}=0.001$. So to determine mutation of a specific position I can use the following, where $x$ is a uniformly distributed random variable in the range $[0,1]$:

$x \leq P_{mutate}$

As I would rather than generate random numbers per string element, I would like to calculate first the number of positions that will undergo mutation given $P_{mutate}$ and the sequence length. To do this, I reckon that (where $n$ is the number of mutated positions and $l$ is the sequence length):

$n = \lfloor\frac{P_{mutate}\cdot l}{x}\rfloor$

But this is clearly wrong, as the result is completely different. I am looking for a computationally simple solution that avoids generating random variables per position.

Comment: Where does a Poisson process come into play? Is the number of mutations per position Poisson distributed? What is the “string sequence” exactly?

Comment: I think you might just be looking for the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) if I understand your question correctly...

Comment: @NapD.Lover the chance of mutation at each position is independent (i.e. mutation or not), so I'd like to be able to estimate how many positions were mutated in 100 (for instance), and the result to be equivalent to calculating the chance per position

Comment: @blobber2 I agree with user Goldbug that it sounds like you’re looking for a binomial RV $X\sim \mathcal{B}(n,p)$ with $n=100$ and $p=0.001$. The RV $X$ denotes the number of positions out of $n$ with a mutation, each independently mutating or not with chance $p$. It is approximately Poisson under certain conditions on $np$.

Comment: Specifically, if $0<p_n<1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}np_n=\lambda$ and $X_n\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,p_n)$, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to a $\mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$-distributed random variable.